# SQL server results to file - using a while loop to output to multiple files

Tags: sql-server, file, save, output

I currently have a script which outputs a useful text file in messages, when I select "results to file" a window pops up telling me where I'd like to save the file to.

Would it be possible to have a line that says:
print 'qwerty' to 'C:\desktop\text.txt'

I'd like to skip up the "save to" pop up window and write a while loop to generate multiple text files (I can do the while loop myself I just need to know if it's possible to output results to a file using a simple SQL query instead of the option at the top that opens up a pop up window)

I'm hoping to use a variable to help me with this, for example:
output to '\desktop\documents\'+@filename+'.txt
Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: BCP, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility

Comment: thanks for that but unfortunately I don't seem to have permission to use BCP.

Comment: Option 1, install SQL Server on your own computer, try out BCP whatever you like. Option 2, SSIS package